# QGIS point displacement with features that each have 2 variables

Tags: qgis, point

My goal is to use point disclacement to have a view like this without overlapping symbols:
[image]

However, the result with using point displacement this (QGIS displays only the first attribute):
[image]

[image]

If I remove the cross in the first three categories (R1), the symbols that point in the other direction (R2) are shown on my map. Hence, the existing rules work if I can trick point displacement in displaying both directions.